# Why does my app work locally, but not on shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to deploye my shiny app on shinyapps.io and I get this message :

"An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1)."

I tried to commit setwd line and other stuff but yet I didn't find solution.

The issue might be a wrong file path ? Should I put the "read.csv" line into my server or ui function ?

Here is my code :

```
#setwd(dir = "/media/miles/MILES/Projets & Cours/Master_1/Semestre 2/lardjane/Shiny_app/Projet Shiny")
matches <- read.csv('./matches.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", header=TRUE)

matches <- matches[,c(3,6)]
#summary(matches)

matches$platformid <- as.factor(matches$platformid)
#levels(matches$platformid)

#install.packages('shiny')
library(shiny)
#install.packages('rsconnect')
library(rsconnect)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel("Game time by server"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      

      # Define the sidebar with one input
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("region", "Server:", 
                    choices=levels(matches$platformid)),
        hr(),
        selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
                    label = "Number of bins in histogram (approximate):",
                    choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50),
                    selected = 20),
        hr(),
        checkboxInput(inputId = "individual_obs",
                      label = strong("Show individual observations"),
                      value = FALSE),

        checkboxInput(inputId = "density",
                      label = strong("Show density estimate"),
                      value = FALSE),

        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.density == true",
                         sliderInput(inputId = "bw_adjust",
                          label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                          min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)),
        hr(),
        helpText("Data from Kaggle (2014-2018) League of Legends Ranked Matches.")
      ),

      # Create a spot for the barplot
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("timePlot")  
      )

    )
  )
)





server <- function(input, output) {

  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$timePlot <- renderPlot({

    # Render a histogramme
    hist(matches[matches$platformid==input$region,2], 
            probability = TRUE,
            breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
            main = "Game Time",
            ylab="",
            xlab="Duration (seconds)")

    if (input$individual_obs) {
      rug(matches[matches$platformid==input$region,2])
    }

    if (input$density) {
      dens <- density(matches[matches$platformid==input$region,2],
                      adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    }

  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to add one last request. I would like to display R code just below the plot. That can anyone can get access to both (app result and R code). Is that possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't use images .. copy and paste the message into the question.  You should not use swd() in Shiny or in any script really.

Comment: I find how to display code by using showcase mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swd is not the way to solve this because of how the environments in Shiny (and R in general) work.  When you launch Shiny you actually don't know what physical server your Shiny server is running on.  So you need to use a generic solution.

Try this:

```
matches <- read.csv('./matches.csv', 
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I still have the same issue.

Comment: It tried an ohter way and i get this message : "paths should be to files within the project directory"

Comment: It looks like I was using a wrong directory adress. thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Storage.html, if the csv file is in the same location as the app, try :

```r
matches <- read.csv('matches.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

However, I don't think this is your issue; I think the issue is in your rendering of the plot. You use the `input$region` to generate your histogram, but you don't provide a default value, so it starts as `NULL`, which causes an issue when you try to construct your histogram. You have 2 options to solve this.

Option 1 is to set a default value for `input$region` with:

```r
selectInput("region", "Server:", 
                    choices=levels(matches$platformid),
                    selected = levels(matches$platformid)[1]),
```

Option 2 is to use `req()` so that the histogram will not run if any of its required values are not [truthy](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html):

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$timePlot <- renderPlot({

    req(input$region, input$n_breaks)

    # Render a histogramme
    hist(matches[matches$platformid==input$region,2], 
            probability = TRUE,
            breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
            main = "Game Time",
            ylab="",
            xlab="Duration (seconds)")

    if (input$individual_obs) {
      rug(matches[matches$platformid==input$region,2])
    }

    if (input$density) {
      dens <- density(matches[matches$platformid==input$region,2],
                      adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: The first solution was good but I added your solution to my code. I do thank you too.